# Get Emacs to ignore contents of \Sexpr{} command in Sweave document to prevent incorrect $-based syntax highlighting

Tags: r, emacs, elisp, sweave

When editing an Sweave document in LaTeX (using the Noweb mode), Emacs knows to "ignore" code that is in <<>>= blocks. However, for interstitial \Sexpr{} blocks, this isn't the case. Given that R references by columns via '$' and LaTeX uses $ to set-off equations, these \Sexpr{} blocks often break the syntax highlighting, like so:

[image: Emacs highlighting issue when using Sweave]

I have a very rudimentary understanding the elisp & Emacs syntax highlighting, but my hope is that it might be possible to add something to .emacs that will disable any parsing/$ detection within \Sexpr{}'s.

Comment: I assume you're using AUCTeX.  In the default LaTeX mode that comes bundled with Emacs, this problem is less severe because the $...$ highlighting is only applied for short (single-line) math expressions, so it never "bleeds" like in your snapshot.  IOW a bug report to the AUCTeX authors is in order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I thought emacs with ESS has correct syntax highlighting for Sweave?

Anyway, the easiest "fix" is to just not use the `$` operator but `[[` instead. For example:

```
foo$p.value
foo[['p.value']]
```

Should give the same result. I think `foo$p.value` is just short for `foo[["p.value",exact=FALSE]]`

Answer (score 7):

I don't have a fix either, but I'll pass along my workaround, which is to never (well, rarely) do any processing in `\Sexpr` chunks but instead to store things I want to use in `\Sexpr` in variables, and to do so in the same chunk I do the main calculations in.

```
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
t1 <- chisq.test(someVar)
p1 <- formatC(t1$p.value, format="%f", digits=2)
@

\dots with a $p$-value of \Sexpr{p1}.
```

While there are some downsides to this, I find it helps me to better keep track of what I want to present, and how I want to present it.

As an aside, consider using `formatC` instead of `round` as it can keep significant zeros (ie, 0.10 instead of 0.1).

Comment: Good aside! I didn't know about the formatC thing. It's always driven me mad how R drops significant zeroes.

Comment: This approach also helps in the event of something like `\Sexpr{sprintf"%.2f",my.float)}` where emacs then treats everything after the percent symbol as a comment, which then breaks parenthesis matching, with all sorts of associated ugliness.

Answer (score 5):

I have no good answer for you as I am not an Emacs hacker, so I usually do one of two things:

- Either add a simple   `% $`   comment at the of the line to "close" the math expression from `$` to `$`,
- Or rewrite the expression to not use `$`-based subsetting:
  `round(as.numeric(chisq.test(someVar)["p.value"]), 2)`.