# Escaping characters for text mode in AUCTeX

Tags: r, emacs, syntax, knitr, auctex

I have a problem with my text editor Aquamacs Emacs (GNU Emacs 23.4.1) when use it with `\Sexpr` to print inline the output from R functions. The problem results when the R command includes special characters such as **$** and **%**. Even though Tex parses correctly the string, the text editor doesn't escape the special characters. There are then two consequences: the colour of the text changes starting with `\Sexpr`  indicating-I guess-that the text editor is not treating that part in "text-mode", and (most annoyingly) the 'while typing' spelling check is not performed on the remaining of the text.

Is there any workaround to convince Emacs that the syntax within `\Sexpr{}` should be not treated as Latex syntax but as R syntax?

Comment: Voting to close, not because I don't feel you (I do!) but because I've not seen any better recommendations than those given in response to [this identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876835/get-emacs-to-ignore-contents-of-sexpr-command-in-sweave-document-to-prevent-i)

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen that.