# How to add \Sexpr{} to Emacs/AUCTeX verbatim environment

Tags: emacs, knitr, sweave, auctex

I have the very same problem detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9876835/get-emacs-to-ignore-contents-of-sexpr-command-in-sweave-document-to-prevent-i) caused by the '$'-included in the \Sexpr command-breaking the syntax highlighting of Emacs. Unfortunately no definitive solution has been proposed yet.

Now I read a solution for a similar problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111289/how-to-make-auctex-ignore-syntax-highlighting-within-environment/111316#comment303115_111316) that I am trying to adapt to my situation. The idea is to set \Sexpr as verbatim environment in Emacs' preferences.

I tried

```
(setq LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local '("Sexpr"))
```

but with no result.

Comment: Well, I imagine `\Sexpr` is a *command*, not an *environment* (two different things in LaTeX parlance).

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
(add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces "Sexpr")
```

and restarting `LaTeX-mode` worked for me.